# explain 1 line of C-code and translate it to Python

Tags: python, c, numpy

Can somebody explain me the following line of C-code and translate it into Python? I have no plan....

```
x[IX(0 ,i)] = b==1 ? –x[IX(1,i)] : x[IX(1,i)]
```

The array structure is not important (except that I am interested in a vectorized Numpy form too). I'm interested in understanding the C command. Simplified we can write

```
D = b==1 ? –A : A
```

What does this mean? What is the result of D at the end? What's the role of `–A : A`? How can we write this in Python? How can we write this vectorized in Numpy? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative form:

```
if(b==1)
  D = -A;
else
  D = A;
```

or

```
if(b==1)
  x[IX(0 ,i)] = –x[IX(1,i)];
else
   x[IX(0 ,i)] = x[IX(1,i)];
```

I think in this form it is not difficult to translate to python

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly....then this will be the case:

It's a ternary operator method, it's like an alternate for if else. For eg: in this example if the value of b is equal to 1 i.e. condition is true then -A will be stored in D otherwise it will hold A value in D.